# How to insert a long/BigInt with Node.js MongoDB Driver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object

I try to insert a **long/BigInt** into my MongoDB Database with the Node.js Mongo Driver.

I've already tried with **BigInt**, but it doesn't insert the number (expiry) in the document.

```
let expire = BigInt(parseInt((Date.now() / 1000) + 21600, 10));
let newDoc = {
    type: "group.test",
    expiry: expire
};
collection.insertOne(newDoc);
// it only inserts the type.
```

I want it to save as **BigInt** because we need to get it later with a Java Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigInt is an object in JS you can't just pass it to Mongodb. Take a look at the data types supported by Mongodb.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/

I would suggest storing the BigInt as string in mongodb and let the reader parse it when the document is read.

```
// Note: this function is a simple serializer
// meant to demo the concept.
function bigIntSerializer(num){
  return {
    type: "BigInt",
    value: num.toString()
  };
}

let expire = BigInt(parseInt((Date.now() / 1000) + 21600, 10));
let newDoc = {
    type: "group.test",
    expiry: bigIntSerializer(expire)
};
collection.insertOne(newDoc);
```

Answer (score 2):

use Long

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Long.html

```
const { Long } = require('mongodb');
let expire = BigInt(parseInt((Date.now() / 1000) + 21600, 10));
let newDoc = {
    type: "group.test",
    expiry: new Long(Number(expire & 0xFFFFFFFFn), Number((expire >> 32n) & 0xFFFFFFFFn))
};
```